# Transfer Call of Duty MW3 save from PC to PS3?

Tags: pc, ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I recently decided to free up the PC solely for work and bought a PS3 for gaming. I was wondering if I can transfer my PC MW3 saves and continue to play on the PS3? Or will I have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short and simple: You'll have to start from scratch.

Comment: <rant>while this is the right answer, I find it incredibly inconvenient in this day and age that data transfer is not possible for bits like this. Most likely, settings/achievements/progress/etc are placed in some form of persistant storage (probably XML) and should be easily pushed to other devices if the game developers would be motivated enough to include such options.</rant>

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Not only would it be convenient and useful for the player, but it might result in more sales for the vendor as users might want to both copies in both environments.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell it's even easier when you think of 'simple saves' (something like which levels you have completed on MW3, as opposed to a Skyrim save that has to store way more info) as these can be stored centrally by game developers/publishers in the same way they would store, say, your MW3 multiplayer profile. Then it could be accessed by *any* platform via a consistent interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would have to start from scratch. This would also be breaching the terms and agreements of at least Sony Computer Entertainment of America's terms. I wouldn't try it.